# Flutter Ios Firebase storage uploading stream

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

i am trying to upload file from device to Firebase Storage and displays a uploading progress with upload task snapshot events stream. my implementation works fine in android but not in ios devices snapshot event are in 'connectionState.waiting' , file uploads but stream not works.

```
Stream<TaskSnapshot> upload(BuildContext context) {
 ActionHandler actionHandler = new ActionHandler();
 FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
 String filename = '${DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch}.${widget.result.files.first.extension}';
 Reference firebaseStorageRefrence = firebaseStorage.ref().child(Strings.BUCKET_SHARED_FILES);
 UploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRefrence.child(filename).putFile(File(widget.result.files.first.path!));
 return uploadTask.snapshotEvents;
```

}

above functions i used to return stream and use a streambuilder to listen for events.

```
         StreamBuilder(
          stream: upload(context),
          builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<TaskSnapshot> event) {
            print('Error-> ${event.hasError}');
            print('ConnectionState -> ${event.connectionState}');
            print('StackStace -> ${event.stackTrace.toString()}');
            print('Error->>>${event.error.toString()}');
            if (event.hasData) {
              var progress = ((event.data!.bytesTransferred.toDouble() / event.data!.totalBytes.toDouble()) * 100).roundToDouble();
              print('UploadingProgress -> $progress');
              if (event.data!.state == TaskState.success) {
                print("Uploading Done");
                ActionHandler uploadAction = ActionHandler();
                uploadAction.data = event.data!.metadata!.fullPath;
                uploadAction.success = true;
                uploadAction.message = "Successfully uploaded";
                uploadAction.extra = widget.result.files.first.extension;
                Navigator.pop(context, uploadAction);
              }
              return Caption('$progress%');
            }
            return Caption('$event%');
          },
        )
```

stream event remains connectionState.waiting ... but it works fine in android .... any one can guide the solution.
development machine Using Mac M1, flutter 2.2.3 and dart 2.13.4.
i tried to test in real ios device but same result.